# HFS+ Hard Drive not booting anymore recovery using TestDisk on macOS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, testdisk

I've had a broken external drive: Western Digital - WD Element 4To, for a long while and I finally took the courage to do some research to fix the problem using TestDisk.
But, I think I hit a wall.
When I run the quick search this came back with the following result:

[image]

Now looking around internet I found that there should be only one primary partition.
I do not know which of the HFS is which and I would rather not lose data.
When I switch the first one I get `Structure: OK`, the one below comes back as `Struture: Bad` but only if the top one is put as Primary. And the bottom partition says HFS+ found using backup sector (the one above only shows blocksize)
My question are as follow:

- how do I save both part and is that even possible ?
- How would I achieve this (including a full copy of the disk to
  another disk for instance) ?
- Is there a way to know which partition to choose.

Comment: TestDisk cannot handle Mac disks at all, neither HFS+ nor APFS. It can find the partition tables, but that's about it. https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk You really need a Mac to fix a Mac drive properly. You could set macOS up on an external drive on this Mac, then work from there, if you have no other option.

Comment: I updated the question; it was not a hard drive internal but external. But you mean that which ever drive it is, so long as it is HFS+ or QPFS it will not yield result? What tools do you recommend then ?

Comment: Well, for free there's the macOS built-in Disk Utility, which should at least let you see what the structure *ought* to be. Beyond that you are into paid solutions, DiskWarrior was the best HFS+ fixer ever, but can't deal with APFS at all. Disk Drill is a good recovery tool, but will require a second drive to recover to.

Comment: I gave a try with DiskWarrior it successfully built a new directory but could not replace the original due to a disk malfunction.
Lots of files were repaired and it was asking me to check the preview (where I could copy files from one drive to the other) before the replace. 
Copying from the preview has a lot of failure are you able to explain why ?

Comment: Why… not really, sorry, other than pending hardware fail, but if DW can't fix it, it's very likely unfixable. You can't check SMART info on a USB drive, so you can't see even a generic failure report. If you have access to an old Mac Pro etc with room for multiple internal drives you could check it that way. Alternatively shuck it from the enclosure & try a different USB adapter. A data recovery service might be your next bet, but they won't make any guarantees.